# Can't push rails 4.1.4 app to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, bin

I recently upgraded my app to rails 4.1.4 from rails 4.1.0 and am no longer able to push to Heroku. The issue is the assets:precompile.

I can reproduce the issue locally by running:

```
rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
```

I can get around this issue by running

```
bin/rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
```

Heroku seems to be running `rake assets:precompile`, which is throwing the error, how can I tell Heroku to use `bin/rake`, or am I looking at this wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: This was tracked down to using the gem ActiveAdmin. Once this gem is removed, regular rake works fine. I opened up an issue with them, but they are unsure what is causing it. https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/issues/3273

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar situation where assets:precompile on Heroku was throwing a database error. Turns out one of the gems we were using was making a call to the database which wasn't available yet. See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline.